# Why the same file differs from textarea and file input?

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to make a webform where you can give input as a file or to paste it into textarea. But when the same data arrives to bottle it is different. Data length from the textarea is larger when from file input. Why could this happen?

Comment: Depends on the character encoding. Some encodings use two bytes, others one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode UTF-8 uses one byte, but UTF-16 uses two.

Comment: Can you post some code, along with the difference in length. Also, python2 or python3?

Comment: And line endings.  Is this actually causing a problem, or are you just wondering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect formatting chars getting inserted on the textarea e.g(newline and carriage returns) might be the issue. Have you checked for this?

Comment: lines from textarea end with \r\n and lines from the file end with normal \n. I have never seen \r character in the wild.

Comment: `\r\n` is the standard HTTP line break and is specified for use in headers. I'm not sure what's specified for textareas, but it would not be surprising to see `\r\n` specified there as well, or if it's allowed to be platform-specific, that would require supporting `\r\n` because Windows uses it.

Comment: @Euphorbium, `\r\n` is also the standard Windows line ending, and various file formats and applications use it as a result.